# Query to combine two tables into one based on timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I have three tables in Postgres. They are all about a single event (an occurrence, not "sports event"). Each table is about a specific item during the event.

```
    table_header columns
    gid, start_timestamp, end_timestamp, location, positions

    table_item1 columns
    gid, side, visibility, item1_timestamp

    table_item2 columns
    gid, position_id, name, item2_timestamp
```

I've tried the following query:

```
    SELECT h.gid, h.location, h.start_timestamp, h.end_timestamp, i1.side,
         i1.visibility, i2.position_id, i2.name, i2.item2_timestamp AS timestamp
    FROM tablet_header AS h
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_item1 i1 on (i1.gid = h.gid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_item2 i2 on (i2.gid = i1.gid AND 
         i1.item1_timestamp = i2.item2_timestamp)
    WHERE h.start_timestamp BETWEEN '2016-03-24 12:00:00'::timestamp AND now()::timestamp
```

The problem is that I'm losing some data from rows when item1_timestamp and item2_timestamp do not match.

So if I have in table_item1 and table_item2:

```
gid | item1_timestamp | side         gid | item2_timestamp | name
----------------------------        -----------------------------------
 1  |   17:00:00      | left          1  |   17:00:00      | charlie   
 1  |   17:00:05      | right         1  |   17:00:03      | frank
 1  |   17:00:10      | left          1  |   17:00:06      | dee
```

I would want the final output to be:

```
gid | timestamp | side  | name
-----------------------------
 1  | 17:00:00  | left  | charlie
 1  | 17:00:03  |       | frank
 1  | 17:00:05  | right |
 1  | 17:00:06  |       | dee
 1  | 17:00:10  | left  |
```

based purely on the timestamp (and `gid`). Naturally I would have the header info in there too, but that's trivial.

I tried playing around with the query I posted used different JOINs and UNIONs, but I cannot seem to get it right. The one I posted gives the best results I could manage, but it's incomplete.

Side note: every minute or so there will be a new "event". So the gid will be unique to each event and the query needs to ensure that each dataset is paired with data from the same gid. Which is the reason for my `i1.gid = h.gid` lines. Data between different events should not be compared.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.gid, t1.timestamp, t1.side, t2.name
from t1
left join t2 on t2.timestamp=t1.timestamp and t2.gid=t1.gid
union
select t1.gid, t1.timestamp, t1.side, t2.name
from t2
left join t1 on t2.timestamp=t1.timestamp and t2.gid=t1.gid
```

Comment: Thanks. This is close but the columns are out of order and all of the columns from table 2 that do not match with the timestamp from table 1 are missing.

Comment: What do you mean the columns are out of order? The left join (being outer) should include nulls where there is no match.. the union (vs union all) prevents duplicate rows

Comment: Well when I compare the two tables independently with the output, the individual data is not lining up. To use my sample output in my OP I see (in order) "left left right left". I'm not entirely sure what the issue is.